# 2's complement of multiple bytes in C++

Tags: c++, twos-complement

I need to calculate the 2's complement of a number of consecutive bytes (some kind of custom data type).
This is what I came up with:

- Generating the 1's complement of each byte
- Adding 1 to the last byte and potentially increasing each byte in front in case of a byte overflow.

Is there any smarter way how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the 2's complement of a number of consecutive bytes"? Are you treating the "consecutive bytes" as a single piece of data?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom data type. Imagine an integer with 7-10 bytes

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea then. Just be careful of little-endian vs big-endian order.

Comment: Thanks. Good for pointing out endianess. Indeed, I will split up the data type into multiple integer parts (at a later point) which will then need to account for endianess.

Comment: Of course in the end, the endianess is only what you say it is.